# Laravel 5.4 logout event from session inactivity

Tags: laravel, events, logout

I’m using file sessions and trying to capture when a user is logged out.  Not when they click the button to logout, but when they have left the page still logged in.  I have an event listener setup for logout, but that does not seem to fire.  Does anyone know how to capture or create an event when the session logout occurs.

```
Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => ['App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout',],
```

Answer (score 1):

The session timeout happens on the client side so you won't be able to detect when that happens.

The best you can do is keep an activity log of each user and on each request, store a timestamp for that user.  Then you'd be able to determine whose sessions are expiring by adding the lifetime variable in session.php `Config::get('session.lifetime')` to the latest timestamp in your activity table and comparing that to the current time.

If it's greater than or equal to the current time, you know their session has expired.

You'd likely need to setup a global middleware which updates your activity table which contains at minimum a `user_id` column and a `timestamp` column after each request for logged in users.

Then you'd want to setup a job which runs every minute or so which reads from your activity table, grabs the config value in session.php, and fire's the user logout event for each user it determines has the session expiring.  When that starts firing, your `'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout'` listener should start picking up that event.